# How to count total number of nodes having same attribute value in XML using VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I have following xml code from that i want to find total number of nodes having same attribute value.
**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gfx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Gfx-SE8.xsd">
    <displaySettings displayType="replace" position="useCurrentPosition" securityCode="*" backColor="white" titleBar="true" titleBarText="" maximumTagUpdateRate="1" focusHighlightColor="lime" disableFocusHighlight="false" size="useCurrentSize" width="960" height="540" allowMultipleRunningCopies="false" cacheAfterDisplaying="false" systemMenu="true" minimizeButton="true" sizeToMainWindow="false" showLastAcquiredValue="true" TrackScreenForNavigation="true" TrackName="" allowResizing="false" whenResized="scale" beepOnPress="false" highlightWhenCursorPassesOver="true" interactiveHighlightColor="black" displayOnScreenKeyboard="false" allowButtonActionOnError="true" fieldNotSelectedTextColor="black" fieldNotSelectedFillColor="white" fieldSelectedTextColor="black" fieldSelectedFillColor="white" fieldInErrorNotSelectedTextColor="black" fieldInErrorNotSelectedFillColor="red" fieldInErrorSelectedTextColor="white" fieldInErrorSelectedFillColor="red" startupCommand="" shutdownCommand="" useGradientStyle="false" endColor="teal" gradientStop="50" gradientDirection="gradientDirectionHorizontal" gradientShadingStyle="gradientHorizontalFromRight"/>
    <button name="Button1" height="112" width="293" left="160" top="80" visible="true" wallpaper="false" toolTipText="" exposeToVba="vbaControl" isReferenceObject="false" style="3d" captureCursor="false" highlightOnFocus="true" tabIndex="1">
     <confirm confirmAction="false" buttonSetting="okCancel" titleBar="true" titleBarText="Confirmation" windowPosition="Centered of screen">
            <caption fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="10" bold="false" italic="false" underline="false" strikethrough="false" caption="Are you sure you want to perform this action?"/>
            <imageSettings imageReference="noImage"/>
     </confirm>
    </button>
    <numericDisplay name="NumericDisplay1" height="20" width="264" left="524" top="111" visible="true" wallpaper="false" toolTipText="" exposeToVba="vbaControl" isReferenceObject="false" backColor="white" backStyle="transparent" foreColor="black" fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="10" bold="false" italic="false" underline="false" strikethrough="false" justification="right" fieldLength="22" showDigitGrouping="false" decimalPlaces="0" format="decimal" overflow="showExponent" leadingCharacter="blanks">
        <connections>
            <connection name="Value" expression="5"/>
        </connections>
    </numericDisplay>
    <stringDisplay name="StringDisplay1" height="20" width="276" left="552" top="168" visible="true" wallpaper="false" toolTipText="" exposeToVba="vbaControl" isReferenceObject="false" backColor="white" backStyle="transparent" foreColor="black" fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="10" bold="false" italic="false" underline="false" strikethrough="false" justification="left" dimensionsHeight="1" dimensionsWidth="23" characterOffset="0">
        <connections>
            <connection name="Value" expression="s"/>
        </connections>
    </stringDisplay>
 </gfx>
```

From above code i want to find number of node having attribute value `exposeToVba="vbaControl"`.
I just want total count of nodes.

i am using following code for my other operations, i just want to add above one to this.

```
            `Dim xmldoc As New XmlDataDocument()
            'Dim xmldoc As New XDocument
            Dim iList As XmlNodeList
            Dim iNode As XmlNode
            Dim iAtt As XmlAttributeCollection
            Dim nAtri As XmlAttribute
            Dim fs As New FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

            xmldoc.Load(fs)
        '************Loop for FTView SE and ME***************************'
        If RBSe.Checked = True Or RBMe.Checked = True Then
            Dim attrName As String = "exposeToVba"
            Dim attrValue As String = "vbaControl"

            iList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("displaySettings")
            worksheet.Cells(row, col).value = xmldoc.LastChild.ChildNodes.Count - 2 '***For total objects count***
            Dim Globalobjectscount = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("parameters")  '***For Global object count***
            worksheet.Cells(row, col + 1).value = Globalobjectscount.Count
            worksheet.Cells(row, col + 2).value = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("animations").Count
            worksheet.Cells(row, col + 3).value = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("numericDisplay").Count
            worksheet.Cells(row, col + 4).value = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("numericInput").Count
            worksheet.Cells(row, col + 5).value = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Button").Count

            For Each iNode In iList
                iAtt = iNode.Attributes
```

`

Comment: you can use xpath: count(//*[@exposeToVba="vbaControl"])

Comment: Thank you.....can you please tell me syntax for xpath

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301220

Comment: Hello sir
i have used `xmldoc.SelectNodes(//*[@exposeToVba="vbaControl"])` but it will not working it will give error like **"Expression expected."**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Linq To Xml solution using XDocument class:

```vb
 Dim xcon As String = "the content of your xml file"

 'use XDocument.Load(xmlFileName) to load Xml fIle
 Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xcon) 

 Dim attrName As String = "exposeToVba"
 Dim attrValue As String = "vbaControl"

 Dim myCount As Integer = xdoc.Descendants() _
        .Where(Function(x) x.Attribute(attrName) = attrValue).Count()
 'returns 3
```

Try!

For further information, please see:
[Linq To Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)
[XDocument class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hello sir ...i am using 'Dim xmldoc As New XmlDataDocument()'
and it is already loaded using 'xmldoc.Load(fs)
So how can i use same to achive my requirement.

Comment: Well, as i mentioned, you have to use `XDocument` instead of `XmlDataDocument`. Have you tried to use my code?